# Linux kernel for Nintendo Wii

Tags: kernel, powerpc

I'm trying to compile a Linux kernel for the Nintendo Wii newer than the version 2.6.32 with mike p5 patches, which I have been using since now without problems. Since version 2.6.33 Wii support is included in the mainline kernel, but I can't manage to make it working. I tried using the old .config I used for version 2.6.32 and also the default .config for Wii platform. Of course in all these configs the option Wii platform support is selected but although the Wii seems to execute kernel code (the blue LED flashes) I can't see anything in the TV nor connecting by ssh. 
I tried almost all the branches included the last test version but with always the same result. I also updated my cross compiling tools with no luck.

Am I missing some option or has something changed since version 2.6.32?

Comment: Try compiling your kernel on the Wii with the old kernel running.  When I got my Guruplug, I decided it was easier to compile kernels on that from a Debian install than mess with crosscompiling tools.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do, if you have a `git` tree with both the "2.6.32 mike p5" and 2.6.33 kernels, would be to do a `git bisect` between the two versions.  It will quickly narrow down the commit that causes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Even though a large part of the code was committed into mainline, like platform support, the mainline kernel doesn't support IOS, USB, GameCube Controllers, etc. However, I have found patches on the web that add USB 2.0 support. Also, remember the mainline kernel can only boot on MINI (via BootMii). Oh, almost forgot you can run `make menuconfig` and maybe check the configuration?

Anyway, here is some references that might help:

- http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/Mainline_Kernel,
- http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/Wii:Hardware_Support.